# sys.exit() from with a function when dict is not empty

Tags: python

i'm wondering if this is the most pythonic way to gracefully exit a script from within a function if a condition matches.  I'm checking if a dictionary contains anything.  if it does, i need the script to stop.

So here `mydict` is defined in an earlier function.  Now i want to check if it has entries.

```
def check_missing():
    if bool(mydict) is True:
        print("Dict is not empty, exiting.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        pass

check_missing()
```

is there a better way to do this?  It does work, but I'm not confident it's "pythonic"

There is more functions after this to continue running if this check passes

Comment: What is `return exit` supposed to return? You have no variable by that name.

Comment: It's not typically good flow control to let inner functions decide to exit the program or interpreter at all. That said, calling `sys.exit()` raises the `SystemExit` exception; you can of course raise something else instead that's a little more catchable.

Comment: BTW, note that questions about what's "pythonic" are generally considered too opinion-based to be on-topic here. See [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353), and [Should we treat questions asking for idiomatic versions of code as primarily opinion-based?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269443) on [meta].

Comment: sorry, i updated the code.  I removed the `return exit` thing, that was a bad copy paste

Comment: well `if mydict:` would be a lot more pythonic than this `bool(mydict)` line

Comment: agree with @Chris_Rands, if you are going to make it more pythonic, then just go ahead and check for the dict `mydict` and not have to add a `bool()` either way when you check if a `dict` exists is returns `True` or `False` if it it's not a `dict` or something other than that.

Comment: The answer by @damon using exceptions is a good approach. In real code you would likely catch the exception father up the call stack where you could do something about it, or in this case where it is intended to trigger an exit, you would likely put it all the way up at the `main` level.

Answer (score 2):

To keep your function *pythonic*, I would suggest that you separate the dictionary validation from the control flow of the program. This will make your code easier to test and it will be possible for other parts of your code to call the function without causing the program to exit -- for instance, if you wanted to display a different error message or ask a user to re-enter an input.

To accomplish this, you can restructure your code like so:

```py
import sys

def is_valid_dict(value):
    if value:  # This is the same as calling `bool(value)`
        raise ValueError("The dict is invalid because it is NOT empty")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This code will be run when the program is executed directly, but not when
    # it is imported. This makes it much easier to test.

    example_dicts = [
        {},  # A dict that is empty
        {"a": 1},  # A dict that is _NOT_ empty
    ]

    for value in example_dicts:
        print(f"Testing: {value!r}")
        try:
            is_valid_dict(value)
        except ValueError:
            sys.exit(" -> EXIT: The dict is NOT empty!")

        print(" -> OKAY: The dict is empty.")
        print()  # Print a blank line
```

Running this in the terminal produces this output:

```sh
$ python3 stack_question.py
Testing: {}
 -> OKAY: The dict is empty.

Testing: {'a': 1}
 -> EXIT: The dict is NOT empty!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to import modules, you can always use `quit()` or `exit()`, but it is preferred that you use `sys.exit()` because quit and exit require the site module, and  `sys` can always be imported.